# merge two programs and using output of 1 as input to another

Tags: c#

I am trying to merge two programs, using output of one as an input to other. 
    Program # 1 ends up writing the output and program 2 wants user input both using console. I don't want result of program 1 to be shown as output but rather used as input so that program 2 doesn't ask for user input.

```
    foreach (var item in result)
               {
                    Console.Write(item);
               }
               Console.ReadLine(); 


**end of program 1**



**program 2**

Console.WriteLine("Please, enter numbers");

var numbersStr = Console.ReadLine();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(numbersStr))
        {
            numbersStr = numbersStr.Trim();

and program continues
```

Comment: For 2 or more programs to communicate with each other, there are many ways to do that but they are not trivial. Look into .NET remoting, web services etc. There are many examples online on how to do this and great articles that explain them.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I think .NET Remoting and web services would be inappropriate for interprocess communications on the same machine. Named pipes, mailboxes, etc would be more appropriate.

Comment: @RonBeyer Correct, that is why I said `there are many ways` and wrote `etc.` How do you know it is within the same machine? All I know is that the OP wants 2 processes to communicate with each other.

Comment: that solution sounds complicate...sorry new into programming world. Output of first program is a 6 digit numerical value.

Comment: @Oom Maybe you just want to create two methods and ones calls the other. Are you aware that you can create methods?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just need methods. You don't need two programs.

```
// name this method appropriately!
private static string Program1() {
    string retVal = "";
    // here goes your program 1
    // replace every Console.Write with retVal += ...
    // e.g.
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        retVal += item.ToString();
    }
    return retVal;
}

// name this properly as well
private static void Program2(string input) {
    // program 2 goes here
}
```

In your `Main`,

```
Program2(Program1());
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. However, now system is showing me another error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If this is a trivial program you could write the output of the first program to a file or database. And your second program could read from that.

```
using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(pathOfFile))
{
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        fileWriter.Write(item);
    }
}
```

**end of program 1**

**program 2**

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, enter numbers");

var numbersStr = Console.ReadLine();

var input = File.ReadAllText(pathOfFile)

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    numbersStr = numbersStr.Trim();
}
```